# Is there any way to pass shared expressions as parameters to PowerBI Gateway?

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dataset, tabular, tabular-editor

I'm currerntly trying to deploy Tabular model to a PowerBI Dataset using Tabular Editor.
I have set the Database credetials as shared expressions as below
Do we have any other way of parameterization ? I could not find any solutions for this yet.

[image: Tabular Editor Shared Expressions to Parameterize]

Under the Datasource I'm using those Shared Expressions

[image: Datasource with Shared Expressions]

After deploying into PowerBI Dataset, we can see the parameters with values and Data source credentials tab got deactivated.

[image: PowerBI Dataset settings]

Under Data Gateway connection, below parameters are visible

[image: Shared expressions names]

When I tried to create connection, the passed values are not appearing. its showing paramter names

[image: Parameter names showing not values]

Do we have any other way of parameterization ? I could not find any solutions for this yet.

Comment: Is this a Direct Query or Import dataset?

Comment: @SamNseir It is a converted dataset, which was a tabular SSAS model.

Comment: I can only suggest that you create a simple Power BI dataset in Power BI desktop, connecting to your SQL server with parameters, just for one table, and then compare in Tabular Editor. It feels like something is missing and PBI Service isn't picking it up. For example, I would of thought to of seen table queries under "Shared Expressions" but see only your parameters in there.